# Max and Min using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: matrices, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Suppose A is a symmetric matrix. Show that the maximum and minimum of $\mathbf x ^T A \mathbf x$ subject to the constraint $\mathbf x ^T \mathbf x=1$ are the maximum and minimum eigenvalues of A.

I haven't had much experience with Lagrange multipliers so my ideas written below might be off. Please feel free to help me sort through things!

A symmetric implies $A^T = A$ and $A^{-1}A^T=1$

Here are my ideas- I'm not sure if I'm on the right track...

I need to find $\nabla f=-\lambda  \nabla g$ and I know that if if $f(x) = \mathbf x ^T A \mathbf x$ then $\nabla f= A \mathbf x$ and $g(x) = 1$ (the $g(x)$ is the constraint, right?) so then I will get $A \mathbf x = -\lambda$.

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: $g(x) = x^T x = x^T I x$ for $I$ the square identity matrix.  You need the gradient of $g,$ then solve $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ under the constraint $g=1.$ By the way, actually $\nabla f = 2 A x$ as a column.

Comment: Thank you- so from here I get $2A\mathbf x = \lambda 2 \mathbf x$ which we can cancel the 2's to get $A \mathbf x = \lambda \mathbf x$ which will give us $A = \lambda$ which means that the symmetric matrix A will just be the eigenvalues? I'm not sure if I'm drawing correct conclusions.

Comment: I don't know why you write $A = \lambda,$ the first refers to a square matrix and the second refers to a single real number. $Ax = \lambda x$ is correct, this is precisely the eigenvalue/eigenvector equation, and for symmetric matrices $\lambda$ will always be real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's form the Lagrangian first:

$$L(x,\lambda)=x^TAx-\lambda x^Tx-\lambda=x^T(A-\lambda I)x-\lambda$$

Now, if you take derivative with respect to $x$, and set to zero you get:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}L(x,\lambda)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x^TAx-\lambda x^Tx-\lambda)=2(A-\lambda I)x=0$$

$$\Rightarrow Ax=\lambda x$$

Therefore, $\lambda $ should be the eigen value of $A$, and $x$ should be an eigen vector.

Now, w.l.g, let $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq\ldots\geq\lambda_n$, be the eigenvalues of $A$, and $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ be the corresponding eigenvectors, then you have:

$$Ax_i=\lambda_i x_i$$
$$\Rightarrow x_i^TAx_i=x_i^T\lambda_i x_i=\lambda_i x_i^Tx_i=\lambda_i.1=\lambda_i$$

Therefore, $x_1^TAx_1=\lambda_1$ is the maximum achievable value, and $x_n^TAx_n=\lambda_n$ is the minumum.

Comment: The elements $x$ are matrices. Is one is allowed, mathematically, to take $\partial L/\partial x$. How does one define the derivation of a matrix by a matrix? Is that a well defined mathematical operation?

Answer (score 0):

$g(x) = x^T x$ hence $\nabla g = 2x$.

Comment: $\nabla g = 2 x$

Comment: $2x$$\mbox{}$ $\ $

Comment: sure... I was mislead by the OP