# Duality in quadratically-constrained quadratic program (QCQP)

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, qcqp

I have been given the primal quadratic program with a single quadratic constraint as given below:

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \min\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} & \frac12 x^{T} Q x \\ \text{subject to} & \frac12 x^{T} x  \leq \frac12 \end{array} $$

where $Q$ is an indefinite, symmetric, rational matrix of size $n$. The task is to show that the optimal values of the primal problem as given and its dual agree. That is, there is no duality gap.

I have (perhaps incorrectly) determined the Lagrangian of this program to be
$$L(x,u) = \frac{1}{2}x^{T}Qx+\frac{1}{2}u(x^{T}x-1) = \frac{1}{2}x^{T}(Q+uI)x-\frac{1}{2}u. $$

At this point, after chasing through some circular algebra attempting to solve the dual problem to maximize (over $u$) the infimum (over $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$) of $L(x,u)$ and doing some KKT analysis on the primal problem as given, I can't seem to arrive at the desired result. Further, I understand there is a theorem which says that if there exists a saddle point of the Lagrangian function, then there is no duality gap (Bazaraa, Sherali, and Shetty), yet I can't seem to reconcile any sort of "mathematically tight" guarantee that there exists a saddle point for $L$ (although I have a hunch that there *ought* to be since $Q$ is indefinite, that is, $Q$ is not PD, not PSD, not ND, not NSD).

If anyone happens to see something particularly insightful in all of this, I would really appreciate the input.

Comment: The minimum should be the eigenvector corresponding to the most negative eigenvalue of $Q$, scaled so it lies on constraint hypersphere.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\lambda_{\min}$ be the minimum eigenvalue of $Q$.

The dual function is
\begin{align}
g(u) &= \inf_x L(x,u) \\
&= \begin{cases}
-\infty \quad \text{if } u < -\lambda_{\min} , \\
-\frac12 u \quad \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
The dual problem is
\begin{align}
\operatorname*{maximize}_{u} & \quad -\frac12 u \\
\text{subject to} & \quad u \geq -\lambda_{\min}.
\end{align}
The optimal value for the dual problem is
\begin{equation*}
d^\star = \frac12 \lambda_{\min}.
\end{equation*}

And this is equal to the primal optimal value, according to the standard variational characterization of the eigenvalues of $Q$.

Note: To derive the dual function, I used the following facts.

1. The minimum eigenvalue of $Q + u I$ is $\lambda_\min + u$.
2. Let $M \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be symmetric.  The quadratic function $h(x) = \frac12 x^T M x$ is unbounded below if the minimum eigenvalue of $M$ is negative.  Otherwise, the minimum value of $M$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
Your problem is partially addressed in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753858/max-and-min-using-lagrange-multipliers/753900#753900)

Note that this is one the rare non-convex problems that has a closed form solution and has zero duality gap.